# Can org.json.JSONObject produce {"und":[{"value":"some@one.com"}]}?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to use org.json.JSONObject to build the following target json string:

```
{"und":[{"value":"some@one.com"}]}
```

Here is my code:

```
JSONObject und = new JSONObject();
und.accumulate("und", new JSONObject().put("value", "some@one.com"));   
System.out.println( und.toString() );
```

But it produces the following:

```
{"und":{"value":"some@one.com"}}
```

How can I produce the target json string?

Thanks and regards.

**EDIT**

Thanks to SLaks's input, here is the code that produces the target string:

```
     JSONObject und = new JSONObject();
     JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
     und.put("und", arr);
     arr.put(new JSONObject().put("value", "some@one.com"));
     System.out.println( und.toString() );
```

Comment: You need to make an _array_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at Jackson, it's one of the most efficient and supported JSON libraries available on Java.

If you are familiar with unmarshalling/deserialization, you can turn an POJO into json and vise versa.

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT)
public class SomeBean {
    Und[] und;
    // TODO: Getters and setters

    public static Und class {
        public String value;
        // TODO: Getters and setters 
    }
}
```

If you are directly parsing a JSON string or file, you can use the ObjectMapper class

```
SomeBean someBean = new ObjectMapper().readValue("input goes here", SomeBean.class);

// If you want just a string you can pass in the String class
String json = new ObjectMapper().readValue("input", String.class);
```

If the JSON is coming from a web service, check out Spring's restTemplate, super easy to work with.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
SomeBean someBean = restTemplate.getForEntity("URI goes here", SomeBean.class);

String json = restTemplate.getForEntity("URI goes here", String.class);
```